# Modifying item created with rallyaddnew

Tags: rally

I'm creating a portfolio item with a rallyaddnew button, but I'd like to modify it before it is created.  For example, I'd like to add a particular parent, and add some tags.

I'm guessing I can modify the object in perhaps the beforeCreate() event.  But if I do so what methods do I use?  I see that modifying record.data.Name actually seems to work, but what is the correct way to do it?

For something like parent or tags, I figure I need a Rally.util.Ref object.  But again, what is the  correct way to modify the object?  Doing a record.data.Tags.push(ref) in response to a beforeCreate event again seems a bit direct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `beforeCreate` listener, you're given the record to modify:

```
var addNew = Ext.widget('rallyaddnew', {
    recordTypes: ['User Story'],
    ignoredRequiredFields: ['Name', 'ScheduleState', 'Project'],
    listeners: {
        beforeCreate: function(addNewComponent, record) {
            record.set('Name', 'new name');
            record.set('Parent', '/hierarchicalrequirement/123.js')
        }
    }
});
```

So, use the `record.set` function to set data, and for properties that are references like `Parent` you should use the ref string, like `/hierarchicalrequirement/123.js` (if you have a record, you can get the ref with `record.get('_ref')`.